# Can JAXB/MOXy serialize enums in the same way as regular classes (non-enums)?

Tags: jaxb, moxy

Imagine I have enum defined like this:

```
public enum ArchiveStatus implements Serializable {
  CANDIDATE         (0, "CANDIDATE", "Candidate for archival"),
  IN_LIBRARY          (1, "IN-LIBRARY", ".."),
  FROM_LIBRARY        (2, "FROM-LIBRARY", "..");

  private int id;
  private String shortName;
  private String longName;

  public ArchiveStatus( int id, String shortName, String longName ) {
    ..
  }

  public int getId() { .. }
  public String getShortName() { .. }
  public String getLongName() { .. }
}
```

By default MOXy is going to serialize it to JSON like this:

```
{
   ..
   "archiveStatus": "CANDIDATE",
   ..
}
```

Is there a way to configure MOXy (in the mapping file) to serialize the enum like a regular class:

```
{
   ..
   "archiveStatus": { "id" : 0, "shortName": "CANDIDATE", "longName": "Candidate for archival" },
   ..
}
```

Comment: What's the point of doing this? The _only_ information you need to uniquely identify an enum element is the name.

Comment: The only reason is to preserve the API that returns JSON. I am investigating to see if we can use MOXy to replace home grown JSON serializer.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**ArchiveStatusAdapter**

You can solve this use case by leveraging an `XmlAdapter`.  `XmlAdapter` is a JAXB mechanism that allows you to marshal one type of object as another.

```
package forum10144489;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class ArchiveStatusAdapter extends XmlAdapter<ArchiveStatusAdapter.AdaptedArchiveStatus, ArchiveStatus> {

    public static class AdaptedArchiveStatus {
        public int id;
        public String shortName;
        public String longName;
    }

    @Override
    public ArchiveStatus unmarshal(AdaptedArchiveStatus adaptedArchiveStatus) throws Exception {
        if(null == adaptedArchiveStatus) {
            return null;
        }
        return ArchiveStatus.valueOf(adaptedArchiveStatus.shortName);
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedArchiveStatus marshal(ArchiveStatus archiveStatus) throws Exception {
        if(null == archiveStatus) {
            return null;
        }
        AdaptedArchiveStatus adaptedArchiveStatus = new AdaptedArchiveStatus();
        adaptedArchiveStatus.id = archiveStatus.getId();
        adaptedArchiveStatus.longName = archiveStatus.getLongName();
        adaptedArchiveStatus.shortName = archiveStatus.getShortName();
        return adaptedArchiveStatus;
    }

}
```

**Root**

The `XmlAdapter` can be specified at the field, property, type, or package level using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.

```
package forum10144489;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

public class Root {

    private ArchiveStatus archiveStatus;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ArchiveStatusAdapter.class)
    public ArchiveStatus getArchiveStatus() {
        return archiveStatus;
    }

    public void setArchiveStatus(ArchiveStatus archiveStatus) {
        this.archiveStatus = archiveStatus;
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain classes with the following entry.

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum10144489;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        properties.put("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Root.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader jsonStringReader = new StringReader("{\"archiveStatus\" : {\"id\" : 0, \"shortName\" : \"CANDIDATE\", \"longName\" : \"Candidate for archival\"}}");
        StreamSource jsonSource = new StreamSource(jsonStringReader);
        Root root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(jsonSource, Root.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
{
   "archiveStatus" : {
      "id" : 0,
      "shortName" : "CANDIDATE",
      "longName" : "Candidate for archival"
   }
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlAdapter
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/jaxb.properties